# How to curve every data labels along the individual segments in Sunburst chart?

Tags: highcharts

**My requirement in short Phrase:**

I am looking for a feature in sunburst chart to *curve data labels along the individual segments*. (Something similar to [this Google result](https://images.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fgccontent.blob.core.windows.net%2Fgccontent%2Fblogs%2Flegacy%2Fc1%2F2016%2F11%2FCircularDataLabels.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.grapecity.com%2Fen%2Fblogs%2Fsunburst-chart-roadmap-what-would-you-like-to-see&docid=jftYYR925qUtSM&tbnid=QAGab80aij-cSM%3A&vet=1&w=794&h=781&source=sh%2Fx%2Fim)).

Is there a feature already in sunburst chart?

If yes, can you please provide me with an example?

**My requirement in long Phrase:**

Please have a look at the [attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtCQk.png). It is the highcharts sunburst chart. As you can see in the attachment, though there is a lot of space in every segment, still data label is chopped off and added "..." ellipsis to the end of data label.

Is there a way to use the left out space in the segment to show the data label as much as possible?

Is there a feature already in sunburst chart to curve the text along the segment? (Something similar to [this Google result](https://images.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fgccontent.blob.core.windows.net%2Fgccontent%2Fblogs%2Flegacy%2Fc1%2F2016%2F11%2FCircularDataLabels.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.grapecity.com%2Fen%2Fblogs%2Fsunburst-chart-roadmap-what-would-you-like-to-see&docid=jftYYR925qUtSM&tbnid=QAGab80aij-cSM%3A&vet=1&w=794&h=781&source=sh%2Fx%2Fim)) Or yet to be developed?

If there is a feature already, can you please provide me with an example?

Thanks in advance!

**Already referred suggestions:**

1. [Highcharts: Is it possible to show Sunburst chart series data labels outside the leaf level nodes with connectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47181306/highcharts-is-it-possible-to-show-sunburst-chart-series-data-labels-outside-the)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, we still not implemented such a feature, because it doesn't get enough votes on our UserVoice platform, but all is not lost.

Here is the example which could be helpful for you to do it by yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/Lcnon9ss/ . That example is based on `pie` series type, but it should be quick to fit it to your requirements.

Additionally, you can vote on this feature on the UserVoice platform mentioned above, here is the link: https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/34591699-ability-to-write-the-labels-of-the-sunburst-chart

Kind regards!

Comment: Hi daniel, Thanks for your answer. It was helpful to know there is an option to draw datalabels in an arc shape. I worked out your answer and I need some more help from you. Kindly have a look at [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qzonpdL9/6/). Here I am trying to position "Asia" datalabel inside its respective segment. I don't know how to move it inside. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: In this case you need to change the way of calculating `r` basing on your 
`shapeArgs`. It have to be equal to `(shapeArgs.innerR + shapeArgs.r) / 2`. Here is the example: https://jsfiddle.net/2yjuhgzt/ . You're very close, so now just add another two text paths (for deeper sunburst levels), and should be fine. You can also think about how to handle resizing of the window.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I resolved it by adding a textPath for the datalabels as following:

```
...series:[ ...
  dataLabels: {
    textPath: {
      enabled: true,
      attiributes: {
        startOffset: '10%',
        textAnchor: 'start',
      }
    }
  }
```

and you cann adjust the params 'startOffset' and 'textAnchor' as required.

Answer (score 0):

[image]https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-sunburst-customization-7q4wq

you can customize by hitting this link

```
import { Sunburst } from "@ant-design/charts";

const CustomSunburst = (props) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  function getCustomArray(value) {
    if (value > 0) {
      let arra = [];
      arra.push({ value: value, name: "USER" });
      return arra;
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    var dataa = {
      children: [
        {
          type: "ABC",
          name: `ABC`,
          value: 4,
          children: getCustomArray(2)
        },
        {
          type: "XYZ",
          name: `XYZ`,
          value: 2,
          children: getCustomArray(3)
        },
        {
          type: "MNO",
          name: `MNO`,
          value: 4,
          children: getCustomArray(5)
        }
      ]
    };
    setData(dataa);
  }, []);

  var config = {
    data: data,
    color: ["#00A5A0", "#057DAF", "#05AF79"],
    innerRadius: 0.35,

    interactions: [{ type: "element-active" }],
    sunburstStyle: (datum) => {
      if (datum.path === "ABC / USER") {
        return {
          fill: "#74ECE9",
          fillOpacity: 0.9
        };
      }
      if (datum.path === "XYZ / USER") {
        return {
          fill: "#74C9EC",
          fillOpacity: 0.9
        };
      }
      if (datum.path === "MNO / USER") {
        return {
          fill: "#70F7CC",
          fillOpacity: 0.9
        };
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      customContent: (title, data) => {
        if (data[0]?.name === "ABC / USER") {
          return (
            <div style={{ padding: 10, fontWeight: "600" }}>
              AMC Users Count : {data[0]?.value}
            </div>
          );
        }
        if (data[0]?.name === "XYZ / USER") {
          return (
            <div style={{ padding: 10, fontWeight: "600" }}>
              XYZ Users Count : {data[0]?.value}
            </div>
          );
        }
        if (data[0]?.name === "MNO / USER") {
          return (
            <div style={{ padding: 10, fontWeight: "600" }}>
              MNO Users Count : {data[0]?.value}
            </div>
          );
        }

        if (data[0]?.name === "ABC") {
          return (
            <div style={{ padding: 10, fontWeight: "600" }}>
              AMC Site Count : {data[0]?.data?.data?.value}
            </div>
          );
        }
        if (data[0]?.name === "XYZ") {
          return (
            <div style={{ padding: 10, fontWeight: "600" }}>
              XYZ Site Count : {data[0]?.data?.data?.value}
            </div>
          );
        }
        if (data[0]?.name === "MNO") {
          return (
            <div style={{ padding: 10, fontWeight: "600" }}>
              MNO Site Count : {data[0]?.data?.data?.value}
            </div>
          );
        } else {
          return "NO DATA";
        }
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Sunburst {...config} height={300}></Sunburst>
      <div
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          top: "44%",
          left: "47%",
          fontWeight: "600"
        }}
      >
        Lorem /
      </div>
      <div
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          top: "49%",
          left: "47%",
          fontWeight: "600"
        }}
      >
        Ipsum
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default CustomSunburst;
```